# Вертикальное выравнивание содержимого flex элементов

Tags: flexbox, выравнивание

Выравниваю блоки с помощью flex контейнера.
Получается такая ситуация:

Когда в одном из них текст перемещается на следующую строку - все остальные блоки тоже становятся выше, при этом текст остаётся сверху, нужно, чтобы был по центру.
Подскажите, как выровнять текст в этих блоках по вертикальному центру?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
 <div style="padding: 15px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; background: black; color: white;  flex-wrap: wrap; display: flex;   justify-content: space-around; ">

 <div style="width: 20%; text-align: center; border: 1px solid red;">NATIVE GROUP HDHFJFJFJFJF DJRKTKTK</div>

 <div style="width: 20%; text-align: center; border: 1px solid red">КУРСЫ</div>

 <div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 20%; text-align: center; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid #1AB488; border-radius: 20%; color: #1AB488">Sign Up</div>

 </div>
```

Comment: align-items: center

Comment: Да, но в таком случае размеры блоков тоже уменьшаются. Нужно чтобы они были одинаковыми, но текст по центру

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.inner div {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 15px; text-align: center; font-weight: bold; background: black; color: white;  flex-wrap: wrap; display: flex;   justify-content: space-around; ">

  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner">
      <div>NATIVE GROUP HDHFJFJF DJRKTKTK GROUP HDHFJFJF DJRKTKTE GROUP HDHFJFJF 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner">
      <div>КУРСЫ</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner">
      <div>Sign Up</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```